# xcode wants " " instead " "

Tags: swift, xcode

From time to time i get this error and Its no problem to fix, but I wanna learn how to prevent this:

this code gives error:

```
if let predecessor = myTree.getNode(withValue: 7)?.predecessor()?.key {
    print("Predecessor to 7 should be 5: ", predecessor)
}
```

the error is the space after "key"
[image: not working]

But if i replace with with a new space:

```
if let predecessor = myTree.getNode(withValue: 7)?.predecessor()?.key {
    print("Predecessor to 7 should be 5: ", predecessor)
}
```

[image]

it runs just fine. Does anyone know what gives?

Comment: Is it possible you're typing a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)? (ALT + spacebar on a Mac keyboard)

Comment: It might be helpful if next time it happens copy + paste the code into a text file and run `xxd the_file` and update the question with the hex. (or press undo in your editor to make it happen again and do the same thing)

Comment: Use "Editor->Show Invisibles"

Comment: In 90% of cases the cause is copying code from badly written websites. One of the best way to prevent this is not to copy-paste code from the internet. Always rewrite it manually, it's also a good way to learn.

Comment: I was not copying anything, thats why I could not figure it out. I must have pressed ALT + SPACE, and now I know! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to try to avoid holding alt while pressing the spacebar :)